# WP gallery issue, not responsive on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, gallery, responsive

Im helping out in cleaning up and renovating a website for a friends organisation/art place.

We are working on Gallery of images of the last years of business. 
See link to one of the gallerys-> http://www.stallbergsgruva.se/2018-2/

My problem is when I view the page on mobile (Android and Iphone) the Gallerys melt together and don't display in a nice way. For example it would be nice to have them all in one column or two but atlas separated and not smudged together as it is now.

Im looking for some CSS code that takes care of this. I have tried a bunch of different codes I found on similar issues but nothing affects my gallery. Im new to this code so many I'm missing something?

Im a beginner at code but can handle it if you add a more thorough description of what code and where to add it, etc.

Thank you in advance! // Erik

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by defining width in media queries. I see you have defined

```
.gallery-width: calc((100% - 16px)/2
```

Change it to `.gallery-width:100%` at the resolutions at you which need this result. More info about media queries can be found at

[Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

[Code Screenshot inside colsole](https://imgur.com/a/AMBC1yw)

So in your case let us assume upto 600px you need this result this is how the media query will look like which needs to be added to your css file :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wp-block-gallery .blocks-gallery-item{
     width :100%;
}
}
```